# What does it mean when default route is to a network address?

Tags: cisco, routing, default-gateway

The default route as configured in a Cisco router is as shown below:

```
Gateway of last resort is 103.0.0.0 to network 0.0.0.0
```

What I have came across so far is that the gateway of last resort is configured to a specific IP address such as `172.16.2.1`. In this case where it is a network address, does the router choose the most specific route with lowest metric as the default route IP address? Does this also mean that the default route may change depending on the destination IP address?

Comment: Could it be 103.0.0.0/7? In that case it's just a host address.

Comment: Could it be an indirectly connected loopback /32? Which will require recursive lookup to determine the actual next hop address?

Comment: Could it be a virtual IP address of VRRP?

Comment: Ah, I found this in the routing table, so I believe the default route will go to 103.201.151.2. `103.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 68 subnets, 5 masks
D EX     103.0.0.0/8 
           [170/1793280] via 103.201.151.2, 00:53:25, GigabitEthernet0/0/0`

Comment: Cool, you can also check FIB to make sure. I think in Cisco it's: show ip cef

Comment: Thanks a lot, it does show up there. It seems like FIB is sometimes more informative than routing table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an EIGRP network, how do you advertise a default route to all the routers?

There are a few ways to advertise a default route to the rest of the network.

1. Create a static route on the border router (of the EIGRP domain) and
   redistribute it into EIGRP.
2. Create a summary route (0.0.0.0) on the border router.
3. Use the `default-network` command on the border router to generate a default route.

The 2nd and 3rd techniques will give you the output you've shown.

`default-network` is a hold over from classful routing and is rarely used anymore.

Cisco has some good explanations [here](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/routing-information-protocol-rip/16448-default.html)  and [here](http://cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/enhanced-interior-gateway-routing-protocol-eigrp/200279-Configure-Default-route-in-EIGRP.html).